# Pyramid route for specific document type

Tags: python, routes, pyramid

Pyramid route matching allows for matching documents of a specific type by specifying the file extension, e.g.

```
config.add_route('pyml', "/{name}.pyml")
```

However, I fail to find a solution to apply this pattern to *any* path, including the docRoot. What works is this, but it is not particularly elegant:

```
config.add_route('pyml0', "/{name}.pyml")
config.add_route('pyml1', "/{p1}/{name}.pyml")
config.add_route('pyml2', "/{p1}/{p2}/{name}.pyml")
config.add_route('pyml3', "/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}/{name}.pyml")
config.add_route('pyml4', "/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}/{p4}/{name}.pyml")
config.add_view(hello_pyml, route_name='pyml0')
config.add_view(hello_pyml, route_name='pyml1')
config.add_view(hello_pyml, route_name='pyml2')
config.add_view(hello_pyml, route_name='pyml3')
config.add_view(hello_pyml, route_name='pyml4')
```

I can hardly imagine this should not be possible with just one route, but how?

Comment: This can be done easily using traversing routing instead of URL dispatch routing. On a mobile now, but I'll try to find you an example later. With traversing you need to register only one view, but need to create a Container resource class that gives the nested levels.

Comment: Yes, an example would be a great help. The documentation of the router is rather complex. Looking forward to it!